# Jar of Beans Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator

Where is the link to the exe file? I find text "jar of beans.exe" and beneath it, a note saying wait for the emulator to load and enjoy, or a statement of similar meaning. The text "jar of beans.exe" is, however, not a hyperlink! I need the link.

Comment: http://jar-of-beans.googlecode.com/files/Jar%20of%20Beans%204_1_1.7z  (Let me know if this is the file that you are looking for)

Comment: Actually I refer to one on this page.
http://www.xda-developers.com/android/jar-of-beans-a-portable-android-emulator/

Comment: ... in which I found the thread
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1975675
which has "jar of beans.exe" as mere text and not a hyperlink.

Comment: That page have the link - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1975675 (Search for the word `software thread` inside your page and it will provide this link). Next step when you open the link, look for the large-font word saying `JAR OF BEANS 4.1.1 with Play STORE+ES file Manager and more...on GOOGLE PROJECT!`, which will lead you to the file that I have posted earlier on. Extract that file and click on the `jar of beans.exe` file. (Let me know if you still could not get that link)

Comment: Maybe you can suggest to the author of Jar of Beans to put a word called `DOWNLOAD` that link to the file directly. :D

Comment: To make life easier for everyone, I have include them in my answer to this question.

Comment: Well. Yeah I've fatigues a little bit. I therefore overlooked a humongous "JAR OF BEANS 4.1.1 ..." text. Now it's downoading. Thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, I also thought the same way as you. Then later, I notice that big font words. I believe that the author also encounter many people asking him about where is the link to the file. But anyway, I have include them in the answer for this question. Do mark it as correct if it really solve your problem. Thanks & good luck with the Android emulator.

Comment: True the author is likely to make it more conspicuous! This discussion gave me a good feeling!

Comment: I would prefer it give me 3 simple links - one that link to the folder directory that shows the list of versions that I can download. 2nd link to the documentation (can be a PDF file or a HTML guide) 3rd link to the latest version and marked with a huge word `Download` or represent by a huge download icon. Just a suggestion for the author to consider. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click [here](http://jar-of-beans.googlecode.com/files/Jar%20of%20Beans%204_1_1.7z) to download that file. (version 4.1.1 - file size: 181 MB)

Click [here](http://code.google.com/p/jar-of-beans/downloads/list) to visit that file in the Google Project.

Click [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1975675) to visit the project forum page.

Comment: Also, I hope it'll have a good speed. The emulator I use now takes minutes to boot any AVD I created with it.

Comment: You will need better hardware but one of our friendly moderator - `Matthew Read` mention that it would not make any differences as discuss in here - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18073/endless-loading-for-emulator-on-low-end-netbook. (Seems like Android emulator run slower)